# How to access MongoDB data from old installation?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB on my local machine. I inserted my data in it and the data location is /data/db.
Total size is 238GB.
Accidentally I reinstall the MongoDB on my Local machine. Now it is not showing my databases when I run command "Show dbs"?
The size of data/db is same 238GB.
How can I access my data?
Both the versions of MongoDB are same. I install with same .exe file.

Comment: Are you running MongoDB as a Service? Windows? Linux? Have you tried the `--dbpath=/data/db` option when starting MongoDB via the mongod command?

Comment: I am using on windows. No I didn't try that.

Comment: @IanMercer I tried that command. It is not working. I checked the config file. It is pointing to different data folder. I updated that to my older folder. But still not showing data.

Comment: stop all the running mongodb instances, try starting manually mongod --dbpath /data_path/data --logpath /log_path/mongod.log